# W3C Wordpress Twenty Twelve error

Tags: html, wordpress, w3c-validation

The twenty twelve will display an error by the w3c validation. How can I fix that?

The error problem is with the hgroup

I googled something but that does not work with the current version.

```
<hgroup>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</hgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write output and error code of the validator.

But, as I remember hgroup was dropped from html5 spec.

Comment: Element hgroup not allowed as child of element header in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) You can enter my URL on w3c [link](http://fahrradtraegeranhaengerkupplung.net)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<hgroup>` and `</hgroup>` tags and it should pass

Answer (score 0):

The `hgroup` element is no longer allowed in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), it was [removed in 2013-04](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=21563).

For alternatives, see the section [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#sub-head).